# vscode-insiders signals error but for production is correct

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use `vscode 1.77.3` (on a linux machine and with python extension) and Im pretty satisfied so tried to use the `insiders` version (23-04-28).
I know that insiders is a pre-release version but was really surprised when discovered these errors:

```
cell.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter| QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

> Cannot access member "AlignHCenter" for type "Type[Qt]"   Member
> "AlignHCenter" is unknown

Then I got an error with this piece of code

```
for row in search:
            data = row['data']
            benef = row['beneficiario']
            importo = row['importo']
            causale = row['causale']
            idx = row['idx']
```

> Argument of type "Literal['importo']" cannot be assigned to parameter
> "__key" of type "slice" in function "**getitem**"
> "Literal['importo']" is incompatible with "slice"

The error is present for the other occurence of `row['..']`

Comment: I think you will need to create a reproducible example. From looking at your code, it looks like just the code needs fixing (but hard to say without being able to run and test it). Why do you think this is a problem with VSCode and not just errors in the code.

Comment: this is not VSC but the language extension, are they different versions, maybe the insiders use the pre-lease version of the Python/PyLance extension

Comment: @topsail. Im prety sure it is a VSCode-insiders because that code works correctly with stable version 1.77.3 and with PyCharm
@

Comment: @rioV8 I found a pre-release of python, installed it but the problem is still there

Comment: I think we still need a reproducible example in order to evaluate this error.

Comment: No, the question is which version of the Python extensions do each of the VSC use, if they are the same it is VSC with the problem

Comment: please find out what versions of the python extension each instance of VS Code has and [edit] your post to add that info.

Comment: The problem seems to have disappeared. The error with `Python v2023.6.1`, I installed the pre-release (`Python
v2023.7.11181009`) but the error persisted. This morning I uninstalled the prerelease and the errors disappeared, I reinstalled the prerelease and the errors are gone. I don't know how to explain it.
Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. My code is correct and runs fine. The stable version of VSCode shows no errors, yet the Pylance in the Insiders version complains. The solution for me was to turn-off the "Type Checking Mode" in the Pylance settings. In the stable version it defaults to "off", but in the insiders is set to "basic". Maybe this helps you too.

[image: working settings]